# Best FPGA to work with

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, programming

I want to work on DSP and artificial intelligence for my freshman project, I was thinking on make an FPGA based system, the problem is that I have little experience working with FPGA's; I already know digital design (Katz/Borriello & Harris/Harris level), a little bit of computer architecture and I know enough verilog, C, and assembly programming. I'm asking not for an FPGA suitable for beginners, but an FPGA suitable for learn the basics code implementation on hardware, and go further on projects dealing with cryptography, communications, DSP, speech recognition, computer vision,etc; besides the fun side of games on a VGA screen, etc. I don't know if any FPGA can support those characteristics, so I'm asking here.

PS: I've seen several projects related on those topics implemented on ALTERA FPGA the one with three channel inputs for audio signals.

Comment: You can't do everything.  Pick a topic to work on first, then choose your tools appropriately.

Comment: Ohh, but indeed they are very related, i know almost every FPGA board support VGA modules with some extensions, but i don´t know how to deal with audio, 2D signals. Look out, the topics are not very far from each other, think in a Viterbi decoder, that covers crypto, communications, and DSP. So i don't want to change any paradigm on electronics, i'm just looking for an FPGA that can deal my freshman project and be usable in the future for further projects, i am not looking for all in one FPGA board-

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: no more than 500Us

Comment: You should also do a "gate budget", working out very roughly how much area (and especially RAM) you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having very much else to go on, I'm going to suggest the range of devices that [Digilent](http://www.digilentinc.com/choosing.cfm) offers. I just recently bought their Atlys board which has been more than adequate for my DSP needs. It has video, audio, mostly a bit of everything. It also comes with Xilinx Webpack and some examples to get you started.

**The Basys 2** has 8-bit VGA, a Spartan 3E and is good if you are looking at low-budget. It's also entry level size, so you are going to hit the area roof of the board quite quickly, especially with video. It doesn't have off-board memory, so you won't be able to get into figuring out how to use that. It's the board used in [this course](http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/FPGA_course).

**The Nexys and Atlys** are bigger FPGAs (Spartan 6) and can do more processing, so if you're looking for something to grow into, then one of those is probably a more suitable option. Which one you pick is going to depend on budget, how much RAM you want, and how much you need audio.

I wouldn't recommend these last two for absolute absolute beginners, because there is a bit of a learning curve. But they should be ok for someone with a some experience (especially if you have HDL/EE/DSP experience) and willingness to learn.

I have absolutely no idea what your budget and/or seriousness is though - there are other cheaper boards around that are less powerful.

Comment: Thank you very much, so if i want to make a project, said recognition of spaces in order to avoid an intelligent agent to hit a wall or a table etc. Would you recommend me one with huge RAM and capabilities to work with digital cameras, DSP , image processing, and thats the Nexys or Altys, those are the best for those purposes?

Comment: It would depend how you'd go about with the sensing, IR/RF sensing and motor control would probably only take a few IO pins and the Basys would probably be OK. If you want to process video and sense objects using a camera, that would definitely require the Nexys or Atlys. I'm inclined to go with the Atlys for that application.

Comment: Is the nexys capable of deal with VGA, audio, camera, etc I/O?

Comment: Is the altys equal in storage and abilities with an ALTERA DE2-70 board?

Comment: The Altera board has got the video and audio peripherals, but I don't know their FPGAs well enough to be able to say how well it will perform for video processing
 applications.

Comment: Thank you very much, after your answer and this post http://tristesse.org/FPGA/CheapFPGADevelopmentBoards, i've decided to buy an atlas and start as soon as possible.Thank you very much